# netbeans maven-assembly-plugin builds jar with dependencies but without project classes

Tags: netbeans-7, maven-assembly-plugin

In netbeans 7.2.1 i am trying to build an executable jar with dependencies using the maven assembly plugin. It worked in the past but when building the jar now it contains all dependencies except the classes from the project itself.

When running `clean install assembly:single` the target directory contains 2 jars, icfStatusPage-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar and icfStatusPage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. One contains all dependencies, the other all classes.

The build of the jar with dependencies seems to be ok. (missing pom files are manual installed artifacts).

```
[assembly:single]
Missing POM for cf:conn-fwk-int:jar:1.0
Missing POM for cf:conn-fwk:jar:1.0
Building jar: /Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects2/icfStatusPage/target/icfStatusPage-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Plugin configuration snippet ;

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <debug>false</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>nl.organization.icfstatuspage.IcfStatus</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<properties>
```

Have been googling and trying multiple options with no success till now. 
Any help is welcome !

Cheers,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at the same point you were and had trouble finding an answer, so even though this is an older question, since it still came up in the search when I was stuck, this is the answer.  I think you need to add in the `<executions>` section.  I know next to nothing about Maven, I'm just trying to make it work...  this seemed to do the trick.

```
    <plugin> 
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration> 
          <archive> 
              <manifest> 
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
                  <mainClass>nl.organization.icfstatuspage.IcfStatus</mainClass> 
                  <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries> 
                  <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries> 
              </manifest> 
          </archive> 
          <descriptorRefs> 
              <descriptorRefs>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRefs> 
          </descriptorRefs> 
      </configuration> 
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I got that section from the Maven documentation on [maven-assembly-plugin usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html).